# R Error: subscript out of bounds with by() nested with kappam.fleiss()

Tags: r, function, error-handling, subscript, r-factor

I have a dataframe in which I want to compute interrater agreement (Fleiss Kappa) for multiple raters on multiple levels of my factor, "form."  When I run my code, I get the following error:

```
**Error in factor(ratings[i, ], levels = lev) : subscript out of bounds**
```

Here's a sample of what it looks like:

```
form <- c("B01","B01","B01","B02","B02","B02","B03","B03","B03")
word<-c("arch","avenue","concrete","devotion","equations","moth","piling","relate","cover")
B01200<-c(1,2,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
B01209<-c(3,2,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
B01214<-c(1,3,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
B01228<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, 2,2,1)
B01235<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA ,1,2,3)
B01242<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, 3,3,1)
B02215<-c(NA,NA,NA ,2,1,1,NA,NA,NA)
B02217<-c(NA,NA,NA,2,1,1,NA,NA,NA)
B02222<-c(NA,NA,NA, 3,1,3,NA,NA,NA)
x <- data.frame(form,word,B01200,B01209,B01214,B01228,B01235,B01242,B02215,B02217,B02222)
x$form <-factor(x$form)
by(x,x[,"form"], function(x) kappam.fleiss(x[,-c(1:2)], detail=TRUE))
```

When I look at the underlying structure using str(x), I cannot see what the problem is with my "form" variable.

Here's what it shows:

```
    'data.frame':   9 obs. of  11 variables:
     $ form  : Factor w/ 3 levels "B01","B02","B03": 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
     $ word  : Factor w/ 9 levels "architects","avenue",..: 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 4
     $ B01200: num  1 2 3 NA NA NA NA NA NA
     $ B01209: num  3 2 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
     $ B01214: num  1 3 2 NA NA NA NA NA NA
     $ B01228: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA 2 2 1
     $ B01235: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA 1 2 3
     $ B01242: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA 3 3 1
     $ B02215: num  NA NA NA 2 1 1 NA NA NA
     $ B02217: num  NA NA NA 2 1 1 NA NA NA
     $ B02222: num  NA NA NA 3 1 3 NA NA NA
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

"Missing data are omitted in a listwise way" within the [irr package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/irr/irr.pdf), also by the `kappam.fleiss()` function, to calculate kappa values correctly. This means basically, that at least one of your cases has to be rated by all readers for the function to execute without error (i.e. no `NA`). In your data none of the rows qualifies for this (i.e. every case has at least one `NA`).

To make it clear by example:

- Works: `kappam.fleiss(data.frame(c(1,3,4), c(1,3,3)))`
- Still Works: `kappam.fleiss(data.frame(c(1,3,4), c(1,3,NA)))`
- Still Works (but only gives you NaN): `kappam.fleiss(data.frame(c(1,NA,4), c(1,3,NA)))`
- Gives an error (like in your case): `kappam.fleiss(data.frame(c(1,NA,4), c(NA,3,NA)))`

Depending on what you want to do you might restructure your data, or split it up and test the subsets separately?